# Magento cachen in header: welcome and cart when session expired

Tags: session, magento, caching, cookies, cart

It seems my Magento is showing wrong information in my header. When the session expires, it still shows information for a specific user. When I return to the website after a day, I did still see "welcome rolandow!", but then when I click this to access "my account", it asks for my login details.

The welcome message I solved by checking in the Header block with IsLoggedIn() if the user is still logged in. But now it also shows my shopping cart while I am logged out.

It shows the actual shopping cart of the user account that I last used to log in. If I open another browser, alter my shopping cart, and then refresh the browser with expired session, the cart is renewed, so the data must be pulled out of the DB. When I click my account, or want to finish the checkout, it asks for login.

So this must be a cookie / cache problem.

I am using APC cache on the server. I don't have caching plugin's installed. Version is 1.6.2.0.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, this was probably just the setting "Persistent Shopping Cart" which can be found under System -> Configuration -> (Customers) Persistent Shopping Cart.